# NHibernate designers

Tags: nhibernate, orm, nhibernate-mapping

I wanted to look through NHibernate however I've not detected free NHibernate designers.
Maybe it is general to map entities manually for NHibernate? I don't think so as it is a lot of work.
Could you share free designers with me and community?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean map from entity to nhibernate-mapping or from database to entity+mapping?

Comment: I don't believe there are any free mappers that are actually worth using.

Comment: to Paco, the second one 'database to entity+mapping'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fluent NHibernate with Automapper is great check it out.

http://fluentnhibernate.org/

http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping

The automapper will automatically map your entities based on a set of conventions and overrides.